# Tableau Desktop - Create customized filter based on multiple values

Tags: binary, tableau-api, binary-logic

I am struggling to find a solution to create customized filter using Parameter. I have excel sheet with sample data as following.

```
*-----------------*
| Customer | Type |
*-----------------*
|  A       |   E1 |
|  A       |   E2 |
|  B       |   E1 |
|  B       |   E2 |
|  C       |   E1 |
|  D       |   E2 |
*-----------------*
```

I want to create a filter with three values as following

```
- E1 & E2
- E1
- E2
```

So when I select Type E1 & E2 then Customer A and B should be displayed. Same when I select Type E1 then Customer C should be displayed.

I have tried to get to the final result but no success so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By second filter `E1` do you mean `E1 and not E2`?

Comment: Assuming the above, I think your problem is to make which filter which works on values for 'inclusion' and 'exclusion' simultaneously.  Therefore, I have proposed a solution based on binary number system approach.  Do let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a slightly different approach, assuming that not too much factors/levels are present in `type` field.

Create a calculated field `Dummy1` with calculation as follows

```
{
Fixed [Customer]: SUM
(IF [Type] = 'E1' then 1 else 10 END)
}
```

This field will act like a binary number with every place as either inclusion or inclusion of any particular value.  Like..

For value 1 - It will filter E1 only (second filter value in your example)
For value -10 - It will filter E2 only (third filter value in your example)
For value- 11 - It will filter E1 and E2 both (first filter value in your example).
Therefore your steps may be-

Create another calculated field `dummy2` as below

```
CASE [Dummy1]
when 1 Then 'E1 but not E2'
WHEN 10 then 'E2 but not E1'
when 11 then 'E1 and E2'
END
```

You can now create filter through `dummy2` as desired

[image: Screenshot]

One more thing, if you have more values in type field, allocate them values as 1, 10, 100, 1000, and so on so that you can distinguish the type which one to include and which one to include depending upon the binary places in their FIXED sum value.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps.

1. Create a parameter to record the user's response/choice. You can think of a parameter as a global variable that can hold a single value. You can also think of a parameter as the way you get a response from the user when you ask the user a question. Parameters have a data type and can (optionally) have restrictions on the list of possible values. So you could make a string valued parameter called "Desired Type" and allow the values "E1", "E2", "All". Show the parameter control.

By itself the parameter doesn't do anything except ask the user the question and record his (single) response

2. Now use the parameter value to filter your data. For example, create a calculated field called "Include Type?" with a definition like

[Desired Type] = "All" or [Type] = [Desired Type]

(I name boolean fields with a trailing ? by convention, you don't have to do that if you don't like that convention).

Finally, place your calculated field [Include Type?] on the Filter shelf and choose to only show values that evaluate to True. Now when you change parameter value, the filter will adjust to include only data rows that match your choices.

Note this particular filter could be created without a parameter, just by showing a Filter control for the field Type, and choosing single value and allowing the All choice. But the approach described above allows you to customize in many different ways because you put whatever logic you like in the calculated field.